# [React][flux][EventEmitter] this reference changes in component to store ref

Tags: reactjs, dispatcher, flux

I have a component, an action and a store, using React & Flux.

When I'm dispatching an event from the Store to a method in my component, "this" ref in my Component changes to the "Store" ref.

Do you guy have any idea of why this is happening?

The store is dispatching event here, in the getAllVotes() method: https://huit.re/voteStoreRow41

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

import dispatcher from '../dispatcher/dispatcher.jsx';
import request from 'superagent';
import nocache from 'superagent-no-cache';

const BASE_URL = "http://odu.priv/ws";

class VoteStore extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.votes = [];
        this.voteComponent = {};

        dispatcher.register(this.handleActions.bind(this));
    }

    getAll(){
        return this.votes;
    }

    setVotes(listVote){
        this.votes.push(listVote);
        this.emit('change');
    }

    getAllVotes(){
        this.emit('change');
    }
```

And the component is handling this event here: https://huit.re/votesL33 where "this" changes to voteStore's ref in the updateVote() method.

```
import React from 'react';

import { Vote } from '../vote/vote.jsx';
import voteStore from '../../stores/voteStore.jsx';

import { getAllVote } from '../../actions/voteActions.jsx';

class Votes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('const ->  ', voteStore);
    this.state = {
      votes : voteStore.getAll()
    }; 
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    voteStore.on('change', this.updateVote);
    getAllVote();
    console.log("Votes ", this.state.votes);
  }

  /*componentWillUnmount() {
    voteStore.removeListener('change',this.updateVote);
  }*/

  updateVote(){
    console.log('this -> ',this);
    console.log('voteStore -> ',voteStore)
    this.setState({
      votes : voteStore.getAll()
    });
    console.log('this.state',this.voteComponent.votes);
  }
```

What I just don't understand is why my "this" ref if not my "votes" instance anymore as soon as the "getAllVotes()" method is called in the store. This causes "this.state" on the below row to be undefined.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are required to post a minimum representation of the problem here, not a third-party site that may change or disappear tomorrow.

Comment: Both links point to the same row. Strange. Please update

Comment: @Rob sorry about that. I updated the content. Tiny links are pointing to my personal Git repository. No doubt it will not disappear tomorrow... ;) I just though it would be easier to directly show code properly formatted, that can be cloned for full details.

Comment: @DamienLeroux I updated that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem come from your class Vote when you add the eventListener you are calling `this.updateVote` you should call this function this way `this.updateVote.bind(this)` as you call a function from your virtual DOM.